# Difference between "click on" "click" "tap" "press it down" "press" "hold it down" "hit"

Tags: word-usage

I have a few questions.

Say I'm teaching someone how to do something on their phone, let's say there are a ton of options on this person's phone and I have to tell them to choose one of the options with their fingers, and let's say sometimes I also need to tell this person to **hold down** this or that option or **press down on this or that** for a few seconds so other options will pop up (Are you still following?). Say I gotta tell this person to select one of the options very quickly what should I say?

Can you please **tap on/tap** that option? 
**Hit on/hit** that option? 
**Click on** that option? 
**Click** this option?

Is **to hold down** and **to press down on** even right? or is it more common to say "press and hold this option"?

Is there a need for a preposition (ON) to indicate where the person needs to go for words such as **"hit, click, tap"**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a touch-screen interface, you generally use the verb **tap** or sometimes **touch**, while **press** and **click** are more often associated with finger-initiated mechanical movement (like a mouse button).

It is correct to use either **tap** or **tap on**, but **tap** without the preposition is probably more common (and more concise):

> **Tap** the icon that looks like an envelope to open your email.

If you need them to hold their finger to the screen, then **tap and hold** will usually work, or even better might be **touch and hold**, since "tap" has the implication of being a quick action:

> **Touch and hold** the icon that looks like an envelope to open the options menu.

Some people use the term **long tap**, but that's UX jargon that shouldn't be used with the general public unless you specifically define the term.   It would be appropriate for a software specification written for a user interface developer, who would be expected to know the jargon:

> **Long tap** should open the options menu.